# Can I send some info to apple watch from iOS app using Watch Connectivity if apple watch inactive?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, xcode14, watchconnectivity

I have iOS app and watchOS, I need to get some info from iOS app to watchOS, when apple watch opens in first time.

User opens iOS app -> get userID from backend -> after some time opens apple watch -> get info from backend using userID from iOS app

How can I do this?

Keychain with iCloud doesn`t fit me. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would put it in a shared storage. Using AppGroup

Comment: @loremipsum Is it okey using App Group with private info?

Comment: It is less secure than a local version but there are plenty of encryption providers and “private info” is usually stored in keychain. So it all depends

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when there is an active session. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) say:

> Most transfers happen in the background when the receiving app is
> inactive.

Specifically, when a watch session is active, you can use

- [updateApplicationContext(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615621-updateapplicationcontext) This function transfers some info, but overwrites any previously sent application context.
- [transferUserInfo(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615671-transferuserinfo) This function is used, if all transferred data are needed, i.e. previously sent data are not overwritten, but queued.
- [transferFile(_:metadata:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615667-transferfile) This function is used to transfer not a user info, but a file.
- [transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615639-transfercurrentcomplicationuseri) This function transfers data to update watch complications.

All of them work in the background.